# how to create a table with column for storing multiple line text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql.I need to create a table for saving employee details "employee id, name, date of birth,address and phone".

What is the query to create such a table. Address field should be multiline text

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) do you not understand that keeps you from creating such a table?

Comment: i created a table using the query :                             CREATE TABLE inventory
(
   id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(50) ,
   address VARCHAR(50),
   dob DATE, phone INT
);

Comment: So what's the question? If you have a query, what's the issue? By the way, if you are not going to to arithmetics (adding, subtracting and such), on phone numbers, don't use `INT` for them (how do you ensure that those starting with `0` don't loose it, for example).

Comment: thank you @oded. will change INT to varchar, the issue is that,when i used int there is an error " the conversion of the varchar value '8547292426' overflowed an int column." so was not sure where i went wrong.

Comment: @Oded, I created a new table as you mentioned. but is it possible that i can change my field property of a table from INT to varchar that is once created

Comment: It is sometimes possible to do so, but you may need to convert the data. A safe way it to add a new column, migrate the data, make sure it is correct, then delete the original column and rename the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [birth_date] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [phone] [varchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [address] [text] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Abdu Ghadia ,thank you. that helped me out.